# PL/SQL Loop through a list and find values which not exists in database table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a list of names. But this list is quite big(10000+ items). I want to go through this values list and list down values which doesn't exist in the table.

I was able to come up with this,

```
 select i.column_value as country_code
 from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('AU', 'IN', 'ZA', 'DK', 'CH', 'NL')) i
 where not exists (select null
                   from country c
                   where c.country_code = i.column_value)
```

but it limits the number of values to be provided to the function as 1000. Thus I'm not able to give to provide full list at once

```
ORA-00939: too many arguments for function
```

Does anyone know a solution to this.

Comment: Where is your list of 10000+ items coming from - another table, or a file, or... surely you aren't typing them in?

Comment: Yes. I'm typing but not really. I'm copying those data from a file. It's already formated. So I just have to copy them in to the function.

Comment: Why not just load the codes into a table and OUTER JOIN to the country table?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really stuck with fixed lists of values, you could union together several table collection expressions, in a subquery (inline view):

```
select i.column_value as country_code
from (
  select * from table(SYS.odcivarchar2list(
    'AU', 'IN', 'ZA', 'DK', 'CH', 'NL' -- up to 999 entries
  ))
  union all
  select * from table(SYS.odcivarchar2list(
    'AU', 'IN', 'ZA', 'DK', 'CH', 'NL' -- up to 999 entries
  ))
) i
where not exists (select null
                  from country c
                  where c.country_code = i.column_value)
```

I tend to use `odcivarchar2list` rather than `dbms_debug_vc2coll` but it should work with either.

If the data is in a file and you can make that available on the database server you might be able to load it as [an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html), which would involve less manual work.

Comment: Splitting records in to 999 chunks is the problem which I'm seeking help.

Comment: That isn't really an Oracle problem, it's file/text manipulation before you get to Oracle. How you do that will depend on the file format and the platform (OS) you're on and tools available. I'd really recommend you look into external tables though; or if you can't get the file onto the server, SQL\*Loader from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Alex that **external table** is the way to go, assuming you have permissions to set up a directory and copy the file to the database server. A quick bet would be to query `all_directories` for existing directories and see if you have access to copy your file there. Also, `dba_external_tables` would show you existing external tables (if any) that you can describe to show the syntax.

If you're lacking permissions, you may want to explore [SQL Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-DD843EE2-1FAB-4E72-A115-21D97A501ECC) `sqlldr` to load the codes from raw file onto a database table, which will then make your query easier and faster.

In `sqlldr` use `OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE, PARALLEL=TRUE) UNRECOVERABLE` to speed up the load.

Good luck and chat back here if you need more help.